# Find all shared x-axes in matplotlib and turn off the grid on siblings

Tags: python, matplotlib, gridlines

I'd like to find all shared x-axes siblings (`ax_2 = ax_1.twinx()`) in a pyQt / matplotlib application and turn off their grid.

I tried fiddling around with `ax.get_shared_x_axes().get_siblings(ax)` but this seems overly complicated. I'm looking for a solution similar to the following pseudo-code

```
for ax in all_axes:
    if hasattr(ax,"is_sibling"):
        ax.grid(False)
```

### Edit:

My fiddling around so far is (drawing heavily from http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/get-parent-or-child-from-twinx-or-twiny-td2038.html):

```
for ax in self.fig.axes:
    shared_x = [ax2 for ax2 in ax.get_shared_x_axes().get_siblings(ax) if ax2 is not ax]
    for ax2 in shared_x:
        ax2.grid(False)
```

The list comprehension is supposed to find all sibling axes of `ax` but not `ax` itself. This nearly works, however, the grid of left axis (the "original" axis) is turned off but not the grid of the right axis. I find the documentation of `get_shared_x_axes()` very unhelpful, I don't even understand what is returned.

### Edit 2:

Another, maybe simpler approach, could be to find all axes with y-labels on the right hand side but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: I'm afraid, the solution to this will be exactly fiddling around with `ax.get_shared_x_axes().get_siblings(ax)`. So maybe it's better to share what you have fiddled so far such that people can help with it.

Comment: Why can't you just keep track of those axes, which you have shared beforehands? In the moment you type `ax_2 = ax_1.twinx()` in the code you already know that this is a shared axes.

Comment: Because I have lots of tabs with configurable matplotlib plots that may have one, two or three subplots of which some have a shared axis. I could keep track of the axes somewhere but I think this would make the software difficult to maintain.

Comment: Are we talking about axes which have been shared through `twinx` only, or are there potentially axes which have been shared through other means in the game as well? Do you have access to the original subplot axes (e.g. are they always created via `plt.subplots()`?) At the moment this is a bit of a black-box game.

Comment: Can somebody explain why my questions got downvoted?

Comment: A single downvote can always happen, you never know why people downvote. To speculate: In this case there is of course some room for improvement compared to [ask]. Showing previous research, showing the actual problem with a runnable example, clearly explaining the situation this needs to be used in (see also my previous comment on where this remains unclear). This would be the reasons I did not upvote this; maybe someone else weighted them higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of knowing with certainty which axes of a group of shared axes is the one which has been created via `twinx`. But there are ways to get close to it.

#### Use custom attribute

First let me mention that you may of course create the attribute to query yourself.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["axes.grid"] = True

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2)
ax5 = axes[0,1].twinx()
ax5.is_sibling = True
ax5.plot([2,4,3])
ax6 = axes[1,0].twinx()
ax6.plot([.1,.5,.6])
ax6.is_sibling = True


# later query the is_sibling attribute
for ax in fig.axes:
    if hasattr(ax,"is_sibling"):
        ax.grid(False)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This is by far the cleanest solution.

#### Find twinx axes by order

It *seems*  that in the list of axes obtained via `ax.get_shared_x_axes().get_siblings(ax)`, the original axes is always in the second position.

```
 [twin axes, original axes, possible further shared axes]
```

Hence you may use

```
for ax in fig.axes:
    shared_x = ax.get_shared_x_axes().get_siblings(ax)
    if len(shared_x) > 1:
        for a in [a for i,a in enumerate(shared_x) if i is not 1]:
            a.grid(False)
```

However, I did not find any reason for this always be the case, it is hence just an assumption, which may prove wrong in certain cases.

#### Find twinx by properties

In case the axes you are looking for are shared axes with their ticks on the right side and having the same position as the original axes, one may query those properties. Note however that you might also create twin axes with their labels on the left side, so this also depends on how the axes were created.

```
def is_twinx(ax):
    s = ax.get_shared_x_axes().get_siblings(ax)
    if len(s) > 1:
        for ax1 in [ax1 for ax1 in s if ax1 is not ax]:
            if ax1.bbox.bounds == ax.bbox.bounds:
                if ax.yaxis.get_ticks_position() == "right":
                    return True
    return False

for ax in fig.axes:
    if is_twinx(ax):
        ax.grid(False)
```

Comment: Aah, as Englisch is not my first language, I misinterpreted "sibling" - it was not clear to me that in `ax2 = ax1.twinx()` both axes are like brother and sister, not like mother and son.
And another "Aah": I didn't know that you can create custom attributes just like that - a gaping hole in my python knowledge. I agree, that is the cleanest and safest solution.

Comment: Since English is not my mother tongue either, I just used the name you proposed. You may of course use `ax.es_hermana` or `ax.schwesterachse = True` or whatever you like, just make sure not to overwrite any existing attribute.

Comment: I didn't want to criticize you - I wanted to say I misunderstood the meaning of  `get_siblings(ax)` and the functionalitly behind `twinx()`, creating two axes with the same level of hiararchy. Thanks for pointing out "how to ask" - I guess, I should reread it ...